# Tracking UK visitor's visa application

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, application-status, pakistan

How should I track my UK Visitor's visa application status from Karachi, Pakistan? It has been 8 working days already and I have not received any notification as yet.

Should I call Gerry's and find out?

Comment: Who is Gerry’s?

Comment: The visa application center in Karachi. I just received an email from the embassy that the case has been concluded. Wondering how long will it take to arrive at the visa application center here.

Comment: Does anyone know if they call or text or email?

Comment: What does the email say?

Comment: It says that the case has been concluded. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

On [Gerrys Visa’s Website](https://www.gerrysvisa.com/) there is a field where you can enter your passport number to track your visa application.

Alternatively, you can call them by searching your nearest office [here](https://www.gerrysvisa.com/contact-us) and finding out the phone number.